# JavaScript passing class attributes as parameters to a function

Tags: javascript, function, class, properties

I'm trying to write a connect four game in Javascript embedded in HTML. The scoring function is by far the trickiest part. I've gotten it to a point where it's quite buggy. Winning combinations can be detected so long as they are entered in the following orders: Up, Down, Down-right (diag.)

However, winning combinations will not be realized if they are Up-left, Left, Right, Up-right.

Can someone explain (A) where I'm going wrong?
And (B) Is there a way to write just one class method to accomplish this effect?

For context, I'm using a design ~similar to a linked list, where if a traversal is possible, it will be executed, augmenting the value hop_count. If hop_count reaches 4 a winner is declared via alert.

Any help is appreciated!

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

.dot {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Connect Four</h2>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>

<script>

class GameObject{
  constructor(shape){
    this.shape = shape;
    this.clicks = 0;
    this.count = null;
    this.top_left = null;
    this.top_mid = null;
    this.top_right = null;
    this.mid_left = null;
    this.mid_right = null;
    this.low_left = null;
    this.low_mid = null;
    this.low_right = null;
    this.status = null;
    this.clickEvent();
  };
  clickEvent(){
    this.shape.addEventListener('click',function(){
      this.clicks += 1
      if (this.clicks % 2 == 1){
        this.shape.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        this.status = 'red';
      }else{
        this.shape.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        this.status = 'blue';
      }
      this.navigate_ax1();
      this.navigate_ax2();
      this.navigate_ax3();
      this.navigate_ax4();
    }.bind(this)) // bind callback function to the the correct 'this' context
  };

  navigate_ax1(){
    let color = this.status;
    let current = this;
    let start = current.count;
    let hop_count = 1;
    while (hash_map[current.top_left]!= null){
      if (hash_map[current.top_left].status==color){
        current = hash_map[current.top_left];
        hop_count += 1;
      }else{
        break;
      };
    };
    current = hash_map[start];
    while (hash_map[current.low_right]!= null){
      if (hash_map[current.low_right]==color){
        current = hash_map[current.low_right];
        hop_count += 1;
      }else{
        break;
      };
    };
    console.log(`ax1 hop count ${hop_count}`)
    if (hop_count >= 4){
       alert(`${current.status} wins!`);
    }
  };

  navigate_ax2(){
    let color = this.status;
    let current = this;
    let start = current.count;
    let hop_count = 1;
    while (hash_map[current.top_mid]!= null){
      if (hash_map[current.top_mid].status==color){
        current = hash_map[current.top_mid];
        hop_count += 1;
      }else{
        break;
      };
    };
    current = hash_map[start];
    while (hash_map[current.low_mid]!= null){
      if (hash_map[current.low_mid].status==color){
        current = hash_map[current.low_mid];
        hop_count += 1;
      }else{
        break;
      };
    };
    if (hop_count >= 4){
      alert(`${current.status} wins!`);
    }
    console.log(`ax2 hop count ${hop_count}`)
  };

  navigate_ax3(){
    let color = this.status;
    let current = this;
    let start = current.count;
    let hop_count = 1;
    while (hash_map[current.top_right]!= null){
      if (hash_map[current.top_right].status==color){
        current = current.top_right;
        hop_count += 1;
      }else{
        break;
      };
    };
    current = hash_map[start];
    while (hash_map[current.low_left]!= null){
      if (hash_map[current.low_left].status==color){
        current = current.low_left;
        hop_count += 1;
      }else{
        break;
      };
    };
    if (hop_count >= 4){
      alert(`${current.status} wins!`);
    };
    console.log(`ax3 hop count ${hop_count}`)
  };

  navigate_ax4(){
    let color = this.status;
    let current = this;
    let start = current.count;
    let hop_count = 1;
    while (hash_map[current.mid_right]!= null){
      if (hash_map[current.mid_right].status ==color){
        current = current.mid_right;
        hop_count += 1;
      }else{
        break;
      }
    };
    current = hash_map[start];
    while (hash_map[current.mid_left]!= null){
      if (hash_map[current.mid_left].status==color){
        current = current.mid_left;
        hop_count += 1;
      }else{
        break;
      };
    };
    if (hop_count >= 4){
      alert(`${current.status} wins!`);
    }
    console.log(`ax4 hop count ${hop_count}`)
  };
};


let hash_map = {};
let shapes = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');
let count = 0;

shapes.forEach((shape)=> {
  let s = new GameObject(shape);
  count += 1;
  s.count = count;
  let neighbors = {
  top_left: count-8,
  top_mid: count-7,
  top_right: count-6,
  mid_left: count-1,
  mid_right: count+1,
  low_left: count+6,
  low_mid: count+7,
  low_right: count+8
  }

  for ([key,value] of Object.entries(neighbors)){
    if ((value > 0)&(value < 43)){
      s[key] = value;
    };
  };
  hash_map[count] = s;
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Go to the *actual* error location and fix it. The code is not correctly using a property and there is no such variable with the given name.

Comment: Trivial reproduction / root cause demonstration: console.log(this_variable_does_not_exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to reference the actual object `hash_map` in your `current =` traversal for `mid_left` and the other ones that didn't work.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

.dot {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Connect Four</h2>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>

<script>

class GameObject{
  constructor(shape){
    this.shape = shape;
    this.clicks = 0;
    this.count = null;
    this.top_left = null;
    this.top_mid = null;
    this.top_right = null;
    this.mid_left = null;
    this.mid_right = null;
    this.low_left = null;
    this.low_mid = null;
    this.low_right = null;
    this.status = null;
    this.clickEvent();
  };
  clickEvent(){
    this.shape.addEventListener('click',function(){
      this.clicks += 1
      if (this.clicks % 2 == 1){
        this.shape.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        this.status = 'red';
      }else{
        this.shape.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        this.status = 'blue';
      }
      this.navigate_ax1();
      this.navigate_ax2();
      this.navigate_ax3();
      this.navigate_ax4();
    }.bind(this)) // bind callback function to the the correct 'this' context
  };

  navigate_ax1(){
    let color = this.status;
    let current = this;
    let start = current.count;
    let hop_count = 1;
    while (hash_map[current.top_left]!= null){
      if (hash_map[current.top_left].status==color){
        current = hash_map[current.top_left];
        hop_count += 1;
      }else{
        break;
      };
    };
    current = hash_map[start];
    while (hash_map[current.low_right]!= null){
      if (hash_map[current.low_right]==color){
        current = hash_map[current.low_right];
        hop_count += 1;
      }else{
        break;
      };
    };
    console.log(`ax1 hop count ${hop_count}`)
    if (hop_count >= 4){
       alert(`${current.status} wins!`);
    }
  };

  navigate_ax2(){
    let color = this.status;
    let current = this;
    let start = current.count;
    let hop_count = 1;
    while (hash_map[current.top_mid]!= null){
      if (hash_map[current.top_mid].status==color){
        current = hash_map[current.top_mid];
        hop_count += 1;
      }else{
        break;
      };
    };
    current = hash_map[start];
    while (hash_map[current.low_mid]!= null){
      if (hash_map[current.low_mid].status==color){
        current = hash_map[current.low_mid];
        hop_count += 1;
      }else{
        break;
      };
    };
    if (hop_count >= 4){
      alert(`${current.status} wins!`);
    }
    console.log(`ax2 hop count ${hop_count}`)
  };

  navigate_ax3(){
    let color = this.status;
    let current = this;
    let start = current.count;
    let hop_count = 1;
    while (hash_map[current.top_right]!= null){
      if (hash_map[current.top_right].status==color){
        current = hash_map[current.top_right];
        hop_count += 1;
      }else{
        break;
      };
    };
    current = hash_map[start];
    while (hash_map[current.low_left]!= null){
      if (hash_map[current.low_left].status==color){
        current = hash_map[current.low_left];
        hop_count += 1;
      }else{
        break;
      };
    };
    if (hop_count >= 4){
      alert(`${current.status} wins!`);
    };
    console.log(`ax3 hop count ${hop_count}`)
  };

  navigate_ax4(){
    let color = this.status;
    let current = this;
    let start = current.count;
    let hop_count = 1;
    while (hash_map[current.mid_right]!= null){
      if (hash_map[current.mid_right].status ==color){
        current = hash_map[current.mid_right];
        hop_count += 1;
      }else{
        break;
      }
    };
    current = hash_map[start];
    while (hash_map[current.mid_left]!= null){
      if (hash_map[current.mid_left].status==color){
        current = hash_map[current.mid_left];
        hop_count += 1;
      }else{
        break;
      };
    };
    console.log(hop_count)
    if (hop_count >= 4){
      alert(`${current.status} wins!`);
    }
    console.log(`ax4 hop count ${hop_count}`)
  };
};


let hash_map = {};
let shapes = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');
let count = 0;

shapes.forEach((shape)=> {
  let s = new GameObject(shape);
  count += 1;
  s.count = count;
  let neighbors = {
  top_left: count-8,
  top_mid: count-7,
  top_right: count-6,
  mid_left: count-1,
  mid_right: count+1,
  low_left: count+6,
  low_mid: count+7,
  low_right: count+8
  }

  for ([key,value] of Object.entries(neighbors)){
    if ((value > 0)&(value < 43)){
      s[key] = value;
    };
  };
  hash_map[count] = s;
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This was it exactly, thanks! If you're aware, is there a way to condense the four navigate functions into a single function that can receive directions as function parameters?

Comment: probably the easiest would be to add an array parameter eg: `dirs = ['mid_left', 'mid_right']` and just wrap the traversal while loop in a for of dirs loop and replace references to `hash_map[current.mid_left]` with `hash_map[dir]`, and then additionally wrap with another for of loop for `dirsets = [ ['mid_left','mid_right'], ['top_left','bottom_right'] ... ]`.  If I was going for shortest most elegant looking code possible I'd probably use `.reduce()` and recursion